# How to set selected atribute as event which trigger the onChange(event) method in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to set

```
selected={( props.eSimStore.showAnswerFlag && 
            String.fromCharCode(65 + index) ==  props.eSimStore.question.answer )}
```

as event which trigger `onChange(event)` method.in my code selected is working but it is not set as event and so it is not set as `props.setNewAnswer(String.fromCharCode(65 + index))`. Please someone give a solution.

```
<select
   onChange={(event) => { 
               if (props.eSimStore.examMode != 'read') {
                  let index= +event.target.value;
                  props.setNewAnswer(String.fromCharCode(65 + index));
               }}} 
> {
    props.eSimStore.question.options.map((option, index) => (
       <option
         key = {index}
         selected={( props.eSimStore.showAnswerFlag && 
                     String.fromCharCode(65 + index) == props.eSimStore.question.answer)}
         value = {index}
       >{htmlToReactParser.parse(option)}</option> ))}
</select>
```

Comment: Please someone give me a suggestion. I am stuck here for some days